# serious bug with random numbers

Tags: php, apache

I finally could create a way to reproduce the bug that I am having. When 2 or more users call a page at the same second modsecurity generates the same sequence of random numbers (using rand() function from php) to both users.

Here is a demonstration of the bug:

http://quemfazsite.com.br/em_criacao/modelo9/teste.php

Opening this page, 2 iframes will load and each one should be generating random numbers independetly of each other but both frames are generating the same sequence of random numbers! The very simple source code can be seen below. If you dont see the same sequence I ask you to reload the page a few times till you get the same number sequence.

EDIT: this bug only happens with modsecurity active. If you comment the "LoadModule" line that loads the modsecurity the bug wont happen!

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET["test"])) {

        $output= "";

        for ($i=0;$i<10;$i++) {

                $output.= rand(0,99999999) . "<br />";

        }

        echo $output;

        exit();

}

?>
<iframe src="PUT_THE_SAME_NAME_OF_THIS_FILE_HERE.php?test&953487"></iframe>
<iframe src="PUT_THE_SAME_NAME_OF_THIS_FILE_HERE.php?test&234322"></iframe>
```

Comment: Use mt_rand() instead of rand() but neither produces a random number that can be considered cryptographically secure.... note also that if you salt the random number, then two sequences begun with the same salt will always be identical

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with the modsecurity module or apache at all. I removed the corresponding tags.

Comment: Recommended Reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation

Comment: @GhostGambler I'm sorry to say but you are so wrong. It has to do with modsecurity and you should insert my modsecurity tag back. IF I disable modsecurity the bug does not happen! It only happens with modsecurity enable with the default rules.

Comment: @Sammitch you are right, but the bug happens only with modsecurity active. Disabling modsecurity does not cause this bug!

Comment: @MarkBaker you are right, mt_rand works well but I cant change all my 3 thousand websites I host and tell my customers not to use rand(). It's a minor problem cause it is very rare to this problem happen but a customer of mine encountered it so I was trying to fix it and discovered it's a problem with modsecurity

Comment: As has been said, it's nothing to do with modsecurity.... it's a problem with the seeding of the random number generator, which is why the documentation recommends not using rand() any more

Comment: Note from the docs about seeding mt_rand(): Since PHP 5.2.1, `the Mersenne Twister implementation in PHP now uses a new seeding algorithm by Richard Wagner. Identical seeds no longer produce the same sequence of values they did in previous versions. This behavior is not expected to change again, but it is considered unsafe to rely upon it nonetheless.` What version of PHP are you running for your 3000 websites?

Comment: [It's not mod_security](http://sourceforge.net/p/mod-security/mailman/message/32887651/). If you're not calling `srand()` with different seeds then PHP is going to seed its PRNG with the current `time()`, and that means if you invoke two calls within the same second you're going to get the same result.

Comment: @sammitch and mark baker It's related to modsecurity. If I run the same example without modsecurity it works just fine. Completely fine. The problem only happens with modsecurity enable. I am running the latest version of PHP in my CENTOS 7 with Apache 2.4. As many of you said, I agree that rand() is not supposed to work as I expect, but it works fine with modsecurity disabled. Has anyone tried the example I gave in a server not running modsecurity? You will see it works fine.

Comment: Welp, enjoy chasing that wild goose. I'm going to go investigate a related issue where my car gets worse gas mileage whenever I wear a sweater.

Comment: @Sammitch if you had tried the code I gave in you local apache not running modsecurity you would see that what you say is completely wrong and you dont have any idea what you are saying, sorry for you. Run the code I gave you in your localserver without modsecurity and you will see rand() works REALLY GREAT. Enable modsecurity and rand() will stop working. It's a fact as it's a fact that if you wear a sweater your car will perform worse (more gas needed) cause it's gonna be heavier. You dont need to investigate it, I will spare your time and I am already telling you this another fact.

Answer (score 2):

`rand` is not designed to produce random numbers.  Its purpose is to produce [**pseudorandom numbers**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) that are distributed uniformly between the given endpoints.  If you make a histogram of the numbers you've generated, you'll see that they are indeed uniformly distributed.

The algorithm that generates these numbers is entirely deterministic.  If you provide the same seed (usually based on the current time, as in your example) you'll get exactly the same sequence of numbers.  This is a feature, not a bug: it allows you exploit the statistical properties of the distribution while being able to reproduce the results afterwards by reusing the seed.

If you need the random numbers to be unpredictable, you should be using a [cryptographic RNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator).

If you just want to robustly avoid clashes like this (caused by colliding time-derived seeds), then you'll have to check against some sort of cross-session storage to ensure uniqueness (e.g. a file or database).  If your application requires that the numbers are always unique, then you should be doing this anyway.

Comment: Hi, thank you and you are right, I agree but there is a problem: the rand() is not using time cause if you loop for (i=0;i<1000;i++) echo rand(); you will see that all random numbers will be different despite they were generated almost in the same time. On the other rand, if another person executes the same script as about the same time as the first they will generate the same random sequence. I discovered that if the different between the 2 users is less than 1 second then the sequence will be exactly the same ONLY if and ONLY IF modsecurity is enabled. So I believe what you say isnt accurate

Comment: @Amanda `rand` is seeded by the current time **the first time you call it** – it then keeps state for subsequent calls.  Once you seed a pseudorandom number generator, the sequence of numbers it will generate is determined uniquely.  Again, this behaviour **is** expected.  I'll stress again that if you need unique numbers, you shouldn't be using `rand` in the first place; at the very least, use some hashing algorithm with a low enough collision rate based on the current microsecond (e.g. `sha1` with `microtime`). (But beware that collisions **can** still occur).

Comment: @Amanda As for `mod_security`, I don't know how it works but the difference in behaviour that you're observing is simply to do with how `rand` is seeded and nothing else.  Since `rand` is a bad function anyway, you should be looking at alternatives.  I suggest you read up on (pseudo)random number generation before using them like this.

Comment: thank you for helping me, now I understand you. The time is used in the first rand() and the others depend on this first time. Now I can understand it, but I can asure you that this bug only happens with modsecurity enable. I did many tests with modsecurity disabled and it does not happen, despite the fact that many of you already told me that rand() is a bad function (and I agree). If you run the code I gave you in Apache without mod_security you will never see a colision, not a sequence equal another... it will be all different despite that you all told me rand() isnt good.